# nodejs: npm error after installing a new node version

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm invoking: `npm install nodetime` and I get the following error:

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

I think that it only started to happen after I installed the new node version (but I uninstalled the old version first so I'm not sure).

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed after I invoked the same command from command prompt.